# Can not import Dependencies.scala from top level sbt in multiproject

Tags: sbt

I have a `commons` project in sbt which needs some values stored in a `Dependencies.scala`.

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   └── Dependencies.scala
└── src
    └── main
        └── scala
```

**commons/build.sbt**

```
import Dependencies._

lazy val commons = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := s"$msg commonsproject",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
  )
```

**commons/project/Dependencies.scala**

```
object Dependencies {
  val msg = "Hello world"
}
```

When I run sbt, I get the correct value for `name`

```
[info] Loading project definition from /mydata/workspace/multiproject/commons/project
[info] Set current project to Hello world commonsproject (in build file:/mydata/workspace/multiproject/commons/)
> name
[info] Hello world commonsproject
>
```

Now, I have integrated it in a top level sbt project.

```
├── build.sbt(top level)
├── commons
│   ├── build.sbt
│   ├── project
│   │   └── Dependencies.scala
│   └── src
│       └── main
├── project
│   └── build.properties
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── scala
    └── test
        └── scala
```

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val commons = (project in file("commons"))
  .settings(
    name := "subproject",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
  )


lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "rootproject",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
  ).aggregate(commons)
```

When I run sbt from the top level, it fails with the following error:

```
/mydata/workspace/multiproject/commons/build.sbt:1: error: not found: object Dependencies
import Dependencies._
^
/mydata/workspace/multiproject/commons/build.sbt:6: error: not found: value msg
name := s"$msg commonsproject",
^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.</pre>
```

Can anyone tell if it's possible to keep the `Dependencies.scala` in the `common` project and still be able to run it from a top level sbt ?

The goal would be to be able to run sbt either at the top level or in the subproject while keeping despendencies in each project.

Other design to achieve what I want is also welcome

Thank you

Here is the sample project https://github.com/ccheneson/multiproject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SBT 0.13 docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html):

> You cannot have a project subdirectory or project/*.scala files in the sub-projects. foo/project/Build.scala would be ignored.

In this case your `Dependencies.scala` file is being ignored because `commons` is a sub-project - that's why you can't access it.

Comment: Any idea what the proper way to share dependencies from project to sub-project is?